# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/index/CorruptIndexException

Tags: java, lucene, lsa

i try to implement LSA semantic search using TML library.here is my code where rep1 is a folder that i create and dossier is a folder where i put my txt documents.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Repository repository = new Repository("C:\rep1");

        repository.addDocumentsInFolder("C:/dossier");

        System.out.println("Documents added to repository successfully!");

        SearchResultsCorpus corpus = new SearchResultsCorpus("type:document");
        corpus.getParameters().setTermSelectionCriterion(TermSelection.DF);
        corpus.getParameters().setTermSelectionThreshold(0);
        corpus.getParameters().setDimensionalityReduction(DimensionalityReduction.NUM);
        corpus.getParameters().setDimensionalityReductionThreshold(50);
        corpus.getParameters().setTermWeightGlobal(GlobalWeight.Entropy);
        corpus.getParameters().setTermWeightLocal(LocalWeight.LOGTF);
        corpus.load(repository);

        System.out.println("Corpus loaded and Semantic space calculated");
        System.out.println("Total documents:" + corpus.getPassages().length);

        PassagesSimilarity distances = new PassagesSimilarity();
        distances.setCorpus(corpus);
        distances.start();

        distances.printResults();


    }
```

but I have this error!

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/index/CorruptIndexException
    at main.org.java.PerformingOperationOnCorpus.main(PerformingOperationOnCorpus.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.lucene.index.CorruptIndexException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

thanks in advance

Comment: This library looks outdated. However, the [documentation](http://tml-java.sourceforge.net/) sayes: _To use TML from another java program you have to include TML in your classpath. You can use the provided tml-xxx-core.jar that does not include dependencies to avoid conflicting jars and save disk space._

This means you have to add all required libraries used in **tml** to your project manually. I think you should for an alternative with active support.

Comment: thank you for your answer , any suggestion to implement LSA then

Comment: The only library i know which looks activ and useful is [S-Space](https://github.com/fozziethebeat/S-Space). Hope that helps.